# Unable to load transpiler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have an Angular application running on Node that I recently just started having issues with.  I am having an error with the transpiler: Please see image.

[Chrome Developer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1vpY.png)

So the app was working and I was trying to get mmmagic loaded so that I could evaluate uploaded files.  Well I could not for anohter reason.  But during that process I started updating most of the NPM packages.  I gave up on getting mmmagic loaded and was going to work on something else when I started getting this error.  Based on the image I uploaded I don't undertstand how it is not loading typescript.  I have tried everything that I can think of, updated most packages, change values in the tsconfig.json, systemjs.config.js, reloaded the node_modules...  Typescript is there but for some reason it does not load it.

```
System.config({
transpiler: 'typescript.js',
typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
    target: "ES5",
    module: "commonjs"},
map: {
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'rxjs'    : 'node_modules/rxjs',
},
paths: {
    'node_modules/@angular/*': 'node_modules/@angular/*/bundles'
},
meta: {
    '@angular/*': {'format': 'cjs'},
    'typescript': {
        "exports": "ts"
    }
},
packages: {
    'app'                              : {main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'ts'},
    'rxjs'                             : {main: 'Rx'},
    '@angular/core'                    : {main: 'core.umd.min.js'},
    '@angular/common'                  : {main: 'common.umd.min.js'},
    '@angular/compiler'                : {main: 'compiler.umd.min.js'},
    '@angular/router'                  : {main: 'router.umd.min.js'},
    '@angular/forms'                   : {main: 'forms.umd.min.js'},
    '@angular/http'                    : {main: 'http.umd.min.js'},
    '@angular/platform-browser'        : {main: 'platform-browser.umd.min.js'},
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': {main: 'platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js'}
}
```

});

If there is anything I can upload that might help please let me know.  I seem to have run into a road block with this.

Thanks

---

### UPDATE

So I am still doing some research and was able to get past the original issue by specifying the full path in the systemjs.config.js.

```
map: {
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'rxjs'    : 'node_modules/rxjs',
    'typescript': 'node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js'
},
```

So now I am not getting any issues with not loading the transpiler but now I get this error.

> Error: typescript is not a valid transpiler plugin.

See image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyKbo.png)

I have no idea what this is about now, almost going backwords....

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it end with .js? A 404 is one of few things. Typo, missing, incorrect host configuration

Comment: Originally it worked perfectly with [transpiler: 'typescript'], I changed it to [transpiler: 'typescript.js'] but it had absolutely no affect on it.

Comment: Try .ts extension.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I changed [transpiler: 'typescript'] to [transpiler: 'typescript.ts'] and got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I could not let this one rest.  So the beginning of this issues is documented here

https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1587

It seems the default loader for the transpiler was changed.  So I followed the suggestion from "guybedford" on the thread from above.  Had to install the plugin-typescript and configure it accordingly.  Below is the updated Systemjs.config file.

```
System.config({
transpiler: 'ts',
typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
    experimentalDecorators: true,
    target: "ES5",
    module: "system"
    //module: "commonjs"
    },
map: {
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'rxjs'    : 'node_modules/rxjs',
    'typescript': 'node_modules/typescript/',
    'ts': 'node_modules/plugin-typescript/lib'
},
paths: {
    'node_modules/@angular/*': 'node_modules/@angular/*/bundles'
},
meta: {
    '@angular/*': {'format': 'cjs'},
    'node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js': {
        'exports': 'ts'
    }
},
packages: {
    'app'                              : {main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'ts'},
    'rxjs'                             : {main: 'Rx'},
    '@angular/core'                    : {main: 'bundles/core.umd.min.js'},
    '@angular/common'                  : {main: 'bundles/common.umd.min.js'},
    '@angular/compiler'                : {main: 'bundles/compiler.umd.min.js'},
    '@angular/router'                  : {main: 'bundles/router.umd.min.js'},
    '@angular/forms'                   : {main: 'bundles/forms.umd.min.js'},
    '@angular/http'                    : {main: 'bundles/http.umd.min.js'},
    '@angular/platform-browser'        : {main: 'bundles/platform-browser.umd.min.js'},
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': {main: 'bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js'},
    'ts'                               : {main: 'plugin.js'},
    'typescript'                       : {main: 'lib/typescript.js'}
}
```

});

Comment: did this fix your problem?